# Включение в Apps Script html необходимого письма

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть скрипт в Google Apps Script, который я использую для отправки необходимых писем при заполнении Google Form. Т.е., когда человек отправляет форму, на указанную в определенном столбце электронную почту ему приходит письмо. На данный момент код выглядит так:

Код работает +- правильно. Иногда не приходит первая рассылка, но в целом поправимо. Я же не могу встроить в переменную body нужный мне html код. Как правильно вставить html, чтобы письма отображались корректно? Просто с тем, что я пробую сейчас, у меня просто даже сам Apps Script не сохраняет. Заранее спасибо!

```js
function sendEmailToClient2() {
  
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //Лист текущей таблицы с именем "PP answers", в который загружаются ответы из формы, записан в переменную:
  var listAnswers = ss.getSheetByName('PP answers'); 
  
  //Получен email клиента из ячейки с адресом: последняя строка, 6 ряд, - и записан в переменную:
  var clientEmail = listAnswers.getRange(listAnswers.getLastRow(),6).getValue();

  var clientEmails = listAnswers
  .getRange(2,6,listAnswers.getLastRow()-2)
  .getValues().flat();
if(clientEmails.includes(clientEmail)) {

    var body = 
      'Ты перезаписался на курс Python Pro. Мы свяжимся с тобой и уточним детали';
  // адрес уже есть, отправляем письмо для дубликатов
} else {
  
    var body = 
      'Ты записался на курс Python Pro. Мы свяжимся с тобой и уточним детали';
  // адрес новый, отправляем письмо для новичков
}
  
MailApp.sendEmail(clientEmail, "Ваша заявка получена",'',{htmlBody: body}); 
}
```

- Возникла ошибка: сообщение приходит не только тому, кто добавился в столбец, но и всем тем, кто был до него(((

Comment: Какой именно HTML код вам не удается вставить? В примере в body нет такого кода. И какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @PrianichkinSergey код очень большой, вот скидываю пример письма: 
HTML-письмо стандартное: <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en"><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta и и.д. 

Сейчас + выдает ошибку: Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.
Ранее ее не было

Answer (score 1):

Формирование строк в коде может быть очень затруднительным и непрактичным. Особенно с точки зрения чтения кода. Поэтому используют [сервис шаблонов](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).

В проекте необходимо создать файл `Шаблон письма.html`. *В новой IDE при вводе имени файла его расширение не указывается.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <!-- Стили -->
  <style>
    .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    .bolder {
      font-weight: bolder;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1 class="italic">
      <?!= Заголовок ?>
    </h1>
    <div>
      <p>Здравствуйте,
        <?!= ИмяКлиента ?>!
      </p>
      <p>На вашем счету
        <span class="bolder"><?!= ОстатокСредств ?></span>.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

И в коде обратиться к нему.

```js
function sendEmail() {
  const шаблон = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Шаблон письма');
  шаблон.Заголовок = `Это важное письмо от ${new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru-RU').format(new Date())}`;
  шаблон.ИмяКлиента = 'Сан Саныч';
  шаблон.ОстатокСредств = new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'RUB'
  }).format(50000);

  const htmlBody = шаблон.evaluate().getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'test@test.test',
    subject: 'Письмо от нас!',
    htmlBody
  });
}
```

На всякий случай привел пример создания строки и из кода

```js
шаблон.Заголовок = `Это важное письмо от ${new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru-RU').format(new Date())}`;
```

Обратите внимание, что поддерживаются не все стили. Это нужно учитывать при формировании письма.

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]